# Is console.log the only option for api's that return with content

Tags: javascript, url-shortener

I currently am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vgd which seems to work fine... but will only work if I log to console, and i'm trying to make the link that it shortens return to an alert.

Eg I want to use:

```
vgd.shorten('http://google.com', function(res) {
this.reply(res); //Should reply a shorteneed version of google.com but gives me an error instead.
});
```

But when I use the above code it does not work, on the other hand: When I use:

```
vgd.shorten('http://google.com', function(res) {
console.log(res);
});
```

It does work.

Why does it do this? and how do I fix it?

ERROR:

```
data:    index.js:8934 -     at /home/ubuntu/workspace/UU/commands/base-uu.js:25:9
data:    index.js:8934 -     at Request._callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/UU/node_modules/vgd/index.js:6:3)
data:    index.js:8934 -     at Request.self.callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/UU/node_modules/vgd/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
data:    index.js:8934 -     at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
data:    index.js:8934 -     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/UU/node_modules/vgd/node_modules/request/request.js:1082:10)
data:    index.js:8934 -     at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
data:    index.js:8934 -     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/UU/node_modules/vgd/node_modules/request/request.js:1009:12)
data:    index.js:8934 -     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
data:    index.js:8934 -     at _stream_readable.js:908:16
data:    index.js:8934 -     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Comment: What error do you get? What you're saying doesn't really make sense; that's not how stuff works. What does the code that doesn't work *really* look like?

Comment: "gives me an error"! Have you tried reading the error? This is normally a good place to start.

Comment: PROTIP: Include the *entire* (and *exact*) error message when saying "gives me an error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're inside a callback, the value of `this` has changed.  You need to copy `this` to a variable first.

```
var that = this;
vgd.shorten('http://google.com', function(res) {
    that.reply(res);
});
```